Derivation of Shannon Limit for soft and hard decoders
I've been reading up on some design considerations for FECs, and have been trying to derive a theoretical bound for performance of a FEC.
I have found the following sources, with these images

From https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Evolution-and-status-of-forward-error-correction-Mizuochi-Sugihara/7ca313ec94406f6b1fdb265c3df5244e6c3a5d08

and this one, from https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263767932_Advances_in_high-speed_DACs_ADCs_and_DSP_for_optical_coherent_transceivers.
I've been trying to search the theory for something to help me understand these limits, and how to derive them. Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks!
